# Postgresql 9.2 ??? symbols

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.2, psql

I've installed pg 9.2 on Ubuntu 12.04

```
$ psql
psql: ?????:  ???? "varan" ?? ??????????
```

How to configure it to output correct symbols?

Comment: do other programs work? this looks like your shell doesn't have a correct charset / unicode setup. provide more information including the OS and locale settings of your system and database and the shell/terminal program you're using

Comment: What's the output of the `locale` command? What terminal are you using and what font does it have?

Answer (score 1):

Most likely you are using some non-English locale.

Check what is your `LANG` and`LC_*` environment variables are set to (`locale` command can show you that).

If you want to just use English for your terminal, you can set English locale for current session using

```
export LANG=en_US.UTF-8
```

If you want to make this permanent, one of the simple ways to override locale is to add this line your `~/.bashrc`.

If you want to use non-English locale and not touch `.bashrc`, you may need to fix your terminal or `ssh` client. For `putty`, typical good setting is to use `UTF-8` encoding.